# MongoDB Performance Testing Using Jmeter (Connection Issue)

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter, database-performance

We are trying do performance testing using Jmeter. Database is MongoDB.

Using JSR223 Sampler with Groovy 2.4.10.

```
import com.mongodb.DB;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoDBHolder;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.WriteResult;

DB db = MongoDBHolder.getDBFromSource("admin", "databasename", "username", "password");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("test"); 
long count = collection.getCount();
String result = String.valueOf(count);             
SampleResult.setResponseData(result.getBytes())
```

Getting below error.

```
Response code: 500
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "l4abcddb1232/11.20.132.301:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on databasename to execute command { count: \"test\", query: {} }" , "code" : 13 , "codeName" : "Unauthorized"}
```

Above issue in Dev database.

Also, how to connect SSL to connect mongodb database (QC)?

Thank you in advance!
Bharathi

Comment: why do you think ssl's gonna help you?

Comment: @YuriG Thank you for reply!
Because QC and PROD servers are enabled with SSL. So want to make know how to make a connection using SSL as well.

Comment: but that's not gonna miraculously dissolve your issue with authorization - fix this first

Answer (score 0):

This is more mongodb questions, but see [authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) and [connection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) to start working with authorized user and SSL connection.